# java.util.Function or Java method, which one is best practice?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

Consider I have a Java method which accepts a parameter and returns something.

```
public Employee mapPersonToEmp(Person p) {
     ......
   return new Employee() ;
}
```

But, I can achieve the same thing if I use Java 8 Function. What I mean is, if I create the below function, I will get the same behavior. My question is which one is recommended? which one is better or best practice since the born of Java 8?

```
    Function<Person , Employee> function = p -> {
        ......
        return new Employee() ;
    } ; 

    Employee e = function.apply(new Person());
```

TIA.

Comment: none of them is best practice.. they need to be used when needed. They are not alternatives

Comment: It depends on the context - how and where are you calling this?

Comment: This seems primairly opinion-based. You may have more luck asking this kind of question over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (please check the on-topic page, I am not fully sure that this is on-topic for Code Review).

Comment: Does the second variant give you any advantage over the ordinary method that worked well the last two decades? Do you think, `function.apply(new Person());` is better than `mapPersonToEmp(new Person());`?

Comment: Second example is the case of OverDesign Design Pattern, which might also correlate with some "industry best practice" I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function<Person , Employee> function = p -> {
        ......
        return new Employee() ;
    } ; 

Employee e = function.apply(new Person());
```

Lambdas are used to pass behaviour.
If your requirement is such that different fields of the Person class can be used to create the Employee object and this behaviour needs to be passed throughout the code, then you can use something like the following:-

```
Employee createEmpFromPerson(Function<Person, Employee> func) {
//this class already has a reference to some person object
return func.apply(person);
}
```

Now you can call this the following ways:-

```
createEmpFromPerson((per) -> new Employee(per.getName(), per.getEmail()));
createEmpFromPerson((per) -> new Employee(per.getName(), per.getAddress()));
```

This is a very trivial example which is meant to explain how inbuilt functional interfaces are meant to encapsulate commonly required behaviors.

Obviously, there are much better examples but I hope you understand what I am trying to explain.